# Python - Remove Quotes From Indexed Value

Tags: python

I created a list by joining two `df.column.values`.

```
test.column=df1.column.values+','+df2.column.values
a     b
---   ----
123   456
789   101
```

test output then looks like

```
ab
---
123,456
789,101
```

When I index `test.column[0]`, I get

'123,456'

However, I can't pass this into my API. The API requires

`[123,456]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show `df1` and `df2` head

Comment: How about `test.column = [df1.column.values, df2.column.values]`?

Comment: Unfortunately that approach doesn't concatenate the column values into one value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the dtype of the two dataframes. Is it int/string?
2. If not string then convert it to string and then combine the two df. You can try something like the following:
   test.column= '[' + column.values.astype(str) + ', ' + df2.column.values.astype(str) + ']
   '
   I hope this helps!